# Simpler angular material custom control implementing ControlValueAccessor and MatFormFieldControl interfaces

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to extend the functionality of a material autocomplete component to use server data. I can already achieve this with no issue. I also wanted to make it reusable in multiple forms, for which I had to implement `ControlValueAccessor` and `MatFormFieldControl` interfaces.

But since my custom control is not a complex one as it is only adding some functionality to an existing autocomplete component, I think that I am overcomplicating my design here. This is basically an added layer on top of an `MatInput`, which already implements `MatFormFieldControl` interface.

Can I and how can I simply extend existing controls for simpler customization on existing control? As a beginner I am not able to find example of extending these controls. Can I direct all interface requirements to a child MatInput?

Comment: I think you are taking the recommended approach from their documentation (https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control). I would not recommend changing anything. I know it's a fair amount of code to just add a little functionality, but I believe it's the best and most standard way.

Comment: That explains, why I do not see extensions of existing inputs. But this must also come with a performance penalty because of all that encapsulation.

Comment: I don't really think there is much of a performance impact, not unless you intend to include many instances of the same component on the same page.